# I'm getting an exception deploying a war in my box and it works fine in another one

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, deployment, war

I have a Linux box with the latest version of Java (java/jdk1.7.0_25) and tomcat (apache-tomcat-7.0.42). When I deploy a War I get:

```
ERROR 2013-07-12 09:55:36,591: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'engageOrderConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deliveryDtoToEngageRetailTransactionDelivery': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.company.engage.adapter.converter.customer.CustomerDTOToRetailTransactionCustomerExtension com.company.engage.order.adapter.converter.DeliveryDtoToEngageRetailTransactionDelivery.customerConverter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.company.engage.adapter.converter.customer.CustomerDTOToRetailTransactionCustomerExtension] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

And some other...

The thing is deploying this war in another linux box, it starts with no issues.

I tried several versions of tomcat, I change to OpenJDK. Also, I copy the tomcat from the linux box that is getting the jar deployed with no errors and I'm getting the same errors.

Anyone can shed some light on this?

Edit: [Full Stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5984438)

Comment: Does the box where this is working have something else deployed, in addition to this war?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: `No matching bean of type [com.starmount.engage.adapter.converter.customer.CustomerDTOToRetailTransactionCustomerExtension] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.`

Are you sure that this bean is available?

Comment: I added the full stacktrace.

@reto: yes, the same war is working fine in the linux next to me :(

Comment: @Kummo: Is a class implementing `CustomerDTOToRetailTransactionCustomerExtension` within the .war? If not, where does the other box get this implementation from?

Comment: yes, I think is a deploy problem, the code works fine

Comment: . You want to make sure  CustomerDTOToRetailTransactionC‌​ustomerExtension exists somewhere in the classpath. Just because the same war works in another system doesn't mean the bean is available. For instance the class could be in a jar in tomcat lib directory. Have you looked at catalina.properties file to see what all locations are added to the classpath?

Comment: Is the application working properly in this other box? Can you see it in a browser?

Comment: Yes the app is working properly, I'm deploying to de other box using scp and ssh...
@braindead: I scp the tomcat from the box that is running fine to my box, and when I start it I see the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation qualifier to the dependency in the bean
example:

```
public interface I{

}

public class IImpl1 implements I {
}

public class IImpl2 implements I {
}

class A {
//Without qualifier the exception that you see will be thrown
@Qualifier("impl1")

@Autowired
private I i;
}
```